# How a variable behaves when an object assigned to it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

The application gets an object from the HTML form via the post method like this:

code :

```
app.post("/foo", (req, res)=> {

  const data = req.body;
  const itemId = req.body.id;

  console.log(data);
  console.log(itemId);

});
```

`console.log()` results are:

```
{
  brand: 'foo',
  model: 'foo',
  amount: '10',
  id: '629f3149ffc8f9dcfa56e403'
}
629f3149ffc8f9dcfa56e403
```

On the console, the whole object and the item's value are shown perfectly.

Now when I apply `delete` to remove the `id` *property* from `const data`
**before** assigning `req.body.id` to `itemId`: (position1)

```
app.post("/foo", (req, res)=> {

  const data = req.body;
  // position 1
  delete data.id;
  
  const itemId = req.body.id;
  

  console.log(data);
  console.log(itemId);

})
```

I get `undefined` for `itemId`:

```
{
  brand: 'foo',
  model: 'foo',
  amount: '10',
  
}
undefined
```

But if I use `delete` **after** assigning `req.body.id` to `itemId`: (position2)

```
app.post("/foo", (req, res)=> {

  const data = req.body;
  
  const itemId = req.body.id;
  // position 2
  delete data.id;
  

  console.log(data);
  console.log(itemId);

})
```

I get the `itemId` in the `console`.

```
{
  brand: 'foo',
  model: 'foo',
  amount: '10',
}
629f3149ffc8f9dcfa56e403
```

The **Question** is **why** and/or **how** this happens?

*I embrace any edit on the Question's title/or body for better understanding for anybody. Thanks.*

Comment: I suggest looking at using a library that handles the communication with the Telegram API this saves you a lot of trouble and let's you focus on functionality development, instead of setting paramaters in URL's. [Botogram](https://github.com/python-botogram/botogram), [Telepot](https://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [python telegram bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) are good examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects and values are treated differently in Javascript assignments.

`data` and `req.body` are *objects*, and after the assignment

```js
const data = req.body;
```

they are the *same* object. The object is not copied, but a new pointer to the same object is created.

Now

```js
const itemId = req.body.id;
delete data.id;
```

first copies the value of `id` into a new variable and then deletes the original (`data.id` is the same as `req.body.id`). The copy survives.

```js
delete data.id;
const itemId = req.body.id;
```

first deletes the original `id` and then attempts to copy its value. But by then, it is gone.

Comment: But isn't it like  `const data = req.body` copies property and values into data? and using `delete data.id` shouldn't just delete the id inside the data variable? and leaves the `req.body` which comes from the post request alone? I can't understand it.

Comment: Sorry, the most important part of my answer was still missing. I added it at the beginning. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understood, and if you know any links or references related to the question I would be so happy if you also attach them to your answer.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript is a good reference. I haven't looked for a section that describes exactly what you asked here, however.